# Bootstrap modal on page load not working

Tags: jquery, css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

i am trying to launch a bootstrap modal on loading of my show page in rails app, what i tried is this:

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class='center'>
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-image">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Confirm Your Shipment!</h4>
            </div>
            <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
            <div class="modal-body">
<p>
<h4>
  <strong>PickUp Location:</strong>
</h4>
<h5>
  <strong><%= @load.pickup %></strong>
</h5>

<h4>
  <strong>Delivery Location:</strong>
</h4>
<h5>
  <strong><%= @load.delivery %></strong>
</h5>

<p>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <a href="/shipments" class="btn btn-primary">Confirm</a>
    <a href='edit_load_path' class="btn">Edit</a>
  </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
  });
</script>
```

**css**

```
.modal-header {
    padding:9px 15px;
    border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
    background-color: #87CEEB;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 5px;
     border-top-left-radius: 5px;
     border-top-right-radius: 5px;
 }


.modal-dialog {
  padding-top: 15%;
}

.modal-image{
    background-image: url('/assets/sure.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

this was working previously but stopped working when format my pc and installed a fresh ruby on rails.

i have many others normal in page modals in my app which are working perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just pasted all the code from this article in my file and it worked. Please make sure that you have imported the Bootstrap Javascript file and the jQuery file.

If not, just add this in the end of yout html body tag:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

Let me know if this helped you :)

Comment: hey @callmeniko can you please add the link of the article you are talking about

Comment: I downloaded fresh Bootstrap and added the codes that you put in this question you've posted. I mean the codes from your show.html.erb file

Comment: thanks dude i did exactly the same and it worked fine

Comment: I'm glad we've found the mistake :)

Comment: Hey @callmeniko there's a small problem when i push to heroku i can't click anything on my modal...it's having a little black shadow like something...but in localhost everything is looking good

Comment: hey @callmeniko there is a problem with your solution adding bootstrap.js is making my dropdown not work